# ARR unable to pass through Windows Authentication

Tags: authentication, iis, arr

I have an intranet website which uses windows authentication.  Through AJAX it uses a web service in the same domain which also uses windows authentication.  I'm using ARR as a reverse proxy only (no load balancing) and I am trying to pass the windows authentication through to the web service

The reverse proxy works fine with Basic Authentication but not Windows Authentication.

My physical setup is a single Windows 2008 R2 server with the website, the Web API service and ARR, all on the same server.  I haven't added anything under Server Farm since everything is on the same machine.

I've set the website and the web API service to windows authentication only and the server and default website to allow anonymous only (several articles say ARR must use anonymous). I've set useAppPoolCredentials=true in the site IIS configuration where Windows Authentication is set.

I've tried restricting authentication providers to just NTLM to avoid Kerberos/SPN complications and I have also tried including Negotiate so Kerberos will be used.

For Kerberos, I've set up SPNs for the server NetBIOS and FQDN and the Website and Web Service FQDM using the single domain account used as app pool identity by the ARR, the external website and the internal web service. (ex: setspn -s HTTP/ domain/account)

I can browse directly to the internal web service and my windows authentication is successful but if I use the website the rewritten request to the web service receives a 401.1 error. In Fiddler I can see three requests from my browser to the external website. The last two have my windows authentication in the header. On the server, the IIS log for the internal web service shows no windows account information on the request.

Why would ARR be failing to pass my windows credentials to the service?

Answer (score 0):

The IIS context for ARR proxy must not use Windows authentication. It must be set to anonymous. The backend service that is proxied could use Windows authentication.